# pandas add a value to new column to each row in a group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with several columns. for examlpe:

```
     #  name        abbr    country
0   454 Liverpool   UCL England
1   454 Bayern Munich   UCL Germany
2   223 Manchester United   UEL England
3   454 Manchester City UCL England
```

and I run a function using .gropuby() - but then I want to add to each row of that group the value I calculated once.

The example code is here:

```
def test_func(abbreviation):
  if abbreviation == 'UCL':
    return 'UEFA Champions League'
  elif abbreviation == 'UEL':
    return 'UEFA Europe Leauge'

data = [[454, 'Liverpool', 'UCL', 'England'], [454, 'Bayern Munich', 'UCL', 'Germany'], [223, 'Manchester United', 'UEL', 'England'], [454, 'Manchester City', 'UCL', 'England']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['#','name','abbr', 'country'])
competition_df = df.groupby('#').first()
competition_df['competition'] = competition_df.apply(lambda row: test_func(row["abbr"]), axis=1)
```

and now I would like to add the value of "competition" to all the cases based on group in the original dataframe (df).

Is there a good way (using 'native' pandas) to do it without iterations and lists etc.?

---

Edit 1:

The final output would then be the original dataframe (df) with the new column:

```
    #   name    abbr    country competition
0   454 Liverpool   UCL England UEFA Champions League
1   454 Bayern Munich   UCL Germany UEFA Champions League
2   223 Manchester United   UEL England UEFA Europe Leauge
3   454 Manchester City UCL England UEFA Champions League
```

---

Edit 2:

I managed to get what I want by zipping, but its a very bad implementation and I am still wondering if I could do it better (and faster using some pandas functions) :

```
zipped = zip(competition_df.index, competition_df['competition'])
df['competition'] = np.nan
for num, comp in zipped:
  df.loc[df['#']==num, 'competition'] = comp
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these might be helpful.

```py
import pandas

data = [[454, 'Liverpool', 'UCL', 'England'], [454, 'Bayern Munich', 'UCL', 'Germany'], [223, 'Manchester United', 'UEL', 'England'], [454, 'Manchester City', 'UCL', 'England']]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['#','name','abbr', 'country'])

# option 1
abbreviation_dict = {
    'UCL': 'UEFA Champions League',
    'UEL': 'UEFA Europe Leauge'
}

df['competition'] = df['abbr'].replace(abbreviation_dict)
```

```py
# option 2 using a function
def get_dict_for_replace(unique_values):
    some_dict = {}
    for unique_value in unique_values:
        if unique_value == 'UCL':
            value_1 = 'UEFA Champions League'  # or whatever is complicated
            some_dict.update({'UCL': value_1})

        elif unique_value  == 'UEL':
            value_2 = 'UEFA Europe Leauge'  # or whatever is complicated
            some_dict.update({'UEL': value_2})

    return some_dict

# get your unique values,
unique_values = df['abbr'].unique() 
# get your dictionary
abbreviation_dict = get_dict_for_replace(unique_values)

df['competition'] = df['abbr'].replace(abbreviation_dict)
```

Without knowing your exact problem then this is probably the most general if you want to use a function. Run each calculation once. Pass to the dataframe. You can probably pack your dictionary more efficiently based on your actual requirements.

aside: Using groupby on '#' instead of 'abbr' might have unwanted consequences unless the mapping is 1-to-1.

Comment: thanks, I would like to have the original "df" updated, now the "competition_df". Since in reality the case is more complicated than just the dictionary you suggest, I'd like to ask if there is a way to resolve it with a function instead the dict you suggested.

Comment: Without giving the exact example of your use case it's relatively hard to help. I've edited above to be as general as possible. If what your doing is consistent across all variations of unique values. ```value = unique_value + 10``` then you want to be looking at some description of vectorization.